# How to get part of a big text without losing html tags with php?

Tags: php, html, regex

I get a big content from an API, something like this:

```
Lorem <div class="highlighted">ipsum dolor</div> 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
```

I want to show around 10 words from this content. And also I do not want to miss the `<div class="highlighted">ipsum dolor</div>` part. I mean the `div` and the `class="highlighted"` should not be removed.

I tried this function:

```
 function getPartialContent($content, $words_number)
    {
        $no_tags_content = preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", html_entity_decode(filter_var($content, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

        $words = explode(" ", $no_tags_content);
        $result = implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, $words_number));
        return $result;
    }
```

The only problem is that this function removes all html tags first.
If I don't use `preg_replace` to remove html tags, the result will be something like this (the div is not closed):

```
Lorem sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt is that this <div class="highlighted">ipsum
```

which is not what I want.

I expect the result to be with closed tags or without any tags at all. Usually there are one or two words in the `div`. The number of words in the result is not that important. I just want it to be short, around 10 to 15 words.

Comment: what's ur expected output ?

Comment: @lagripe see the my updated question. last paragraph

Comment: Either you work with [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) _or_ you first count the "words" within html elements and add that number to $words_number to make sure they never get truncated.

Comment: _or_ split by html tags first

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/3dEqDC/1

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$rgxp = '/^(\W*(<[^>]+>\W*)?\w+(\W*<[^>]+>)?\W*){10,15}/';
preg_match($rgxp, $text, $mtch);
echo "\n",$mtch[0], "\n";
```

Expanded:

```
$rgxp = '/
^             # start of line
(             # group to quantify
\W*           # ignore space & punctuation
(<[^>]+>\W*)? # optional opening tag group
\w+           # the words to count
(\W*<[^>]+>)? # optional closing tag group
\W*           # ignore space & punctuation
) {10,15}     # quantifier
/x';
```